# Can all the tables in the database contain foreign keys?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, mariadb

I'm trying to some create tables like this

```
CREATE TABLE department(d_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
e_ssn int,
d_no int primary key,
mng_ssn int,
CONSTRAINT `fk_mng_ssn`
FOREIGN KEY (mng_ssn) REFERENCES Employee (ssn)
ON DELETE null) ENGINE = InnoDB;

create table Employee(f_name varchar(20) not null,
ssn int primary key,
sex varchar(5),
d_no int,
super_ssn int,
CONSTRAINT `fk_d_no`
FOREIGN KEY (d_no) REFERENCES department (d_no)
ON DELETE null) ENGINE = InnoDB;

create table dependant(dependant_name varchar(20) not null,
e_ssn int,
sex varchar(5),
CONSTRAINT `fk_e_ssn`
FOREIGN KEY (e_ssn) REFERENCES Employee (ssn)
ON DELETE CASCADE,
primary key (e_ssn,dependant_name)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

here all the tables contain foreign keys is this the reason that I am getting **errno: 150** "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" in mariadb.

Comment: Try running each one separately. Then you can isolate the error to a given create statement and work on the malformed DDL syntax.

Comment: Is it just the way this is posted, or is the quoted constraint name using the wrong quotes?

Comment: Quoted constraint name was not the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the tables in the proper order to avoid error 150.

Or don't add (via `ALTER TABLE`) the FKs until after `CREATEing` all the tables.

Comment: Adding the foreign keys after creating the tables worked, thanks